# Mixing vertical and horizontal Bootstrap cards with gutters

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm having difficulty setting up a new layout using Bootstrap 5.3. I have a series of cards that are separated by 2-pixel gutters. Two of the cards should be stacked vertically, but using half (or nearly half) of the height of the quarter-width card to the right of them. The content of these cards will be responsive, so the height will change be changing dynamically.

I'd like to add a padding of 2 between the two vertical cards so they do not touch and so that the height of the two vertical cards matches that of the other cards on the same row. How can I accomplish this?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row g-2 mb-2">
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card h-50 text-bg-warning">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="text-uppercase"><strong>Vertical card 1</strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    Adding an mb-2 to this card pushes Vertical Card 2 below the height of the Quarter-Width Card.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card h-50 text-bg-info">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="text-uppercase"><strong>Veritical card 2</strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">Add a spacer between the two vertical cards.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card h-100 mb-2 text-bg-danger">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="text-uppercase"><strong>Quarter-width card</strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" style="height: 300px">A larger amount of text will go here.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12">
            <div class="card h-100 mb-2 text-bg-success">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="text-uppercase"><strong>Half-width card</strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card mb-2 text-bg-primary">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="text-uppercase"><strong>Full-width card</strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is on the column with the 2 cards display them with `flex` and then have the 2 children cards `flex-fill` the available space.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row g-2 mb-2">
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="card text-bg-warning flex-fill mb-2">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="text-uppercase"><strong>Vertical card 1</strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    Adding an mb-2 to this card pushes Vertical Card 2 below the height of the Quarter-Width Card.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-bg-info flex-fill">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="text-uppercase"><strong>Veritical card 2</strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">Add a spacer between the two vertical cards.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card h-100 mb-2 text-bg-danger">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="text-uppercase"><strong>Quarter-width card</strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" style="height: 300px">A larger amount of text will go here.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12">
            <div class="card h-100 mb-2 text-bg-success">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="text-uppercase"><strong>Half-width card</strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card mb-2 text-bg-primary">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="text-uppercase"><strong>Full-width card</strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```